# Getting load library or linking error for XCB plugin of statically linked Qt5

Tags: linux, qt, debian, qt5, xcb

Trying to create C++ Qt5.6.1 application and start it on Debian.
Getting either link error or load library error.

Qt build to a static libs, used configuration

```
configure -release -confirm-license -opensource -static -no-dbus -no-openssl -no-qml-debug -no-opengl -qt-freetype -qt-xcb -nomake tools -nomake tests -nomake examples -no-sql-db2 -no-sql-oci -no-sql-tds -no-sql-sqlite2 -no-sql-odbc -no-sql-ibase -no-sql-psql -skip doc -skip imageformats -skip webchannel -skip webengine -skip webview -skip sensors -skip serialport -skip script -skip multimedia
```

Project created with Cmake, libs are specified in this way:

```
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "${QT5_LIB_ROOT}/cmake")

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Network REQUIRED)

FIND_PACKAGE( PNG REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE( ZLIB REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE( Threads REQUIRED )

IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
   SET(QT_LIBS
      libqtharfbuzzng_debug.a
      libqtpcre_debug.a
      libQt5PlatformSupport_debug.a
      libxcb-static_debug.a
      )
ELSE()
   SET(QT_LIBS
      libqtharfbuzzng.a
      libqtpcre.a
      libQt5PlatformSupport.a
      libxcb-static.a
      )
ENDIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")

SET(OS_SPECIFIC_LIBS
   dl
   Qt5::QXcbIntegrationPlugin
   ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
   ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
   ${PNG_LIBRARY} )

FOREACH(lib_name ${QT_LIBS})
   IF(NOT EXISTS ${QT5_LIB_ROOT}/${lib_name})
      MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not locate required Qt lib ${QT5_LIB_ROOT}/${lib_name}")
   ENDIF()

   LIST(APPEND OS_SPECIFIC_LIBS ${QT5_LIB_ROOT}/${lib_name})
ENDFOREACH(lib_name)
```

And if I'm importing XCB plugin in the code ( Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QXcbIntegrationPlugin) it gives me link error:

```
    /Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.a(qxcbmain.o): In function `QXcbIntegrationPlugin::create(QString const&, QStringList const&, int&, char**)':
qxcbmain.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `QXcbIntegration::QXcbIntegration(QStringList const&, int&, char**)'
```

Anf if I don't import plugin - it just not start with error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
```

Any help? advice?

Thanks.

Comment: I think static linking and CMake is anyhow broken at the moment, cf. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38913 , but this looks like a different issue -- and I think you're not supposed to manually link in the platform plugin, the CMake/Qt integration is supposed to take care of that, but I may be wrong...

Comment: It is a bit different. Issue that I have is specific for linux. Have no issues on OSX and Windows ( different plugin so, platform specific ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple - just link with proper system libs:
fixed with adding

```
FIND_PACKAGE( X11 REQUIRED )

SET(OS_SPECIFIC_LIBS
   ...
   xcb
   X11-xcb
   ${X11_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: Sorry if I missed something obvious, but `nm -gC libqxcb.a` show `QXcbIntegration::QXcbIntegration` as undefined. I don't see how the answer solves that. It doesn't work for me (I have the exact same problem). Is your `CMakeLists.txt` open source so I can take a look?

Comment: This did not work on Qt6.

Answer (score 2):

The solution isn't simple. Maybe you doing something wrong if you are here. But you need to link `res/archdatadir/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.a` and `lib/libQt{$Qt_MAJOR_VERSION}XcbQpa.a`
Dirty example for cmake is here https://github.com/Jihadist/StaticQtPlugin/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L56 and dont't forget `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QXcbIntegrationPlugin)`
Thanx to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672598/emmanuel-lepage-vallee

Comment: Wow, I struggled with this for 2 days. There are pieces of this solution all over Stack Overflow and elsewhere, but you are the first to put it all together. My statically linked Qt6 app now runs on Linux. Thank you MoonRaiser!

Answer (score 1):

(nvm the comment above, I found the problem)

To add to Ation answer, the "future proof" way I found to debug this is to use `qmake` for a minimal sample.

testcase.pro:

```
QT += core gui
QTPLUGIN.platforms = qminimal qxcb
CONFIG -= import_plugins
CONFIG += static
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QXcbIntegrationPlugin)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "Does something!";
    return app.exec();
}
```

Once this exist, run `qmake` and `make`. The `make` output will contain all `-l****` you need to put in the CMake project `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` variable. I can be automated.

Comment: See MoonRaiser's answer below for the CMake solution.